# Shell: find files in a list under a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a list containing about 1000 file names to search under a directory and its subdirectories. There are hundreds of subdirs with more than 1,000,000 files. The following command will run find for 1000 times:

```
cat filelist.txt | while read f; do find /dir -name $f; done
```

Is there a much faster way to do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If `filelist.txt` has a single filename per line:

```
find /dir | grep -f <(sed 's@^@/@; s/$/$/; s/\([\.[\*]\|\]\)/\\\1/g' filelist.txt)
```

(The `-f` option means that grep searches for all the patterns in the given file.)

**Explanation of `<(sed 's@^@/@; s/$/$/; s/\([\.[\*]\|\]\)/\\\1/g' filelist.txt)`:**

The `<( ... )` is called a [process subsitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), and is a little similar to `$( ... )`. The situation is equivalent to (but using the process substitution is neater and possibly a little faster):

```
sed 's@^@/@; s/$/$/; s/\([\.[\*]\|\]\)/\\\1/g' filelist.txt > processed_filelist.txt
find /dir | grep -f processed_filelist.txt
```

The call to `sed` runs the commands `s@^@/@`, `s/$/$/` and `s/\([\.[\*]\|\]\)/\\\1/g` on each line of `filelist.txt` and prints them out. These commands convert the filenames into a format that will work better with grep.

- `s@^@/@` means put a `/` at the before each filename. (The `^` means "start of line" in a regex)
- `s/$/$/` means put a `$` at the end of each filename. (The first `$` means "end of line", the second is just a literal `$` which is then interpreted by grep to mean "end of line").

The combination of these two rules means that grep will only look for matches like `.../<filename>`, so that `a.txt` doesn't match `./a.txt.backup` or `./abba.txt`.

`s/\([\.[\*]\|\]\)/\\\1/g` puts a `\` before each occurrence of `.` `[` `]` or `*`. Grep uses regexes and those characters are considered special, but we want them to be plain so we need to escape them (if we didn't escape them, then a file name like `a.txt` would match files like `abtxt`).

As an example:

```
$ cat filelist.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
blah[2012].txt
blah[2011].txt
lastfile

$ sed 's@^@/@; s/$/$/; s/\([\.[\*]\|\]\)/\\\1/g' filelist.txt
/file1\.txt$
/file2\.txt$
/blah\[2012\]\.txt$
/blah\[2011\]\.txt$
/lastfile$
```

Grep then uses each line of that output as a pattern when it is searching the output of `find`.

Comment: Thanks! what does <(sed 's@^@/@; s/$/$/; s/\./\\./' filelist.txt) mean?

Comment: @Todd, I've expanded my answer :)

Comment: You shouldn't go to such great lengths, trying to re-create patterns programmatically. It's error-prone, and often there are some gray zones or possibilities for extensions in the specification of the pattern language. In this particular case, I think it would be better to just use `grep -F -f FILE`

Answer (score 15):

If `filelist.txt` is a plain list:

```
$ find /dir | grep -F -f filelist.txt
```

If `filelist.txt` is a pattern list:

```
$ find /dir | grep -f filelist.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `xargs(1)` for the while loop can be a bit faster than in bash.

Like this

```
xargs -a filelist.txt -I filename find /dir -name filename
```

Be careful if the file names in filelist.txt contains whitespaces, read the second paragraph in the DESCRIPTION section of [`xargs(1)` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) about this problem.

An improvement based on some assumptions. For example, a.txt is in filelist.txt, and you can make sure there is only one a.txt in /dir. Then you can tell `find(1)` to exit early when it finds the instance.

```
xargs -a filelist.txt -I filename find /dir -name filename -print -quit
```

Another solution. You can pre-process the filelist.txt, make it into a `find(1)` arguments list like this. This will reduce `find(1)` invocations:

```
find /dir -name 'a.txt' -or -name 'b.txt' -or -name 'c.txt'
```

Comment: `xargs -I` will be invoked 1000 times. I just tested this in CentOS 7.  `-I` switches `xargs` to per-input-line mode. From  man pages:
     unquoted  blanks  do  not terminate  input  items;  instead  the  separator is the newline 
     character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
In BSD (MacOS) `-J` would work correctly packing the command line, but `-J` is not available for GNU `xargs`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure of the question here, but I came to this page after trying to find a way to discover which 4 of 13000 files had failed to copy.

Neither of the answers did it for me so I did this:

```
cp file-list file-list2
find dir/ >> file-list2
sort file-list2 | uniq -u
```

Which resulted with a list of the 4 files I needed.

The idea is to combine the two file lists to determine the unique entries. 
`sort` is used to make duplicate entries adjacent to each other which is the only way `uniq` will filter them out.