# Unix find multiple files

Tags: unix, find

I want to find a number of specific files using the find command, preferably naming these files in another file. E.g:
`find . -name < cat list_of_files.txt`

I know there's a way to use the find command to find more than one regexp:
`find . -name "<regexp1>" -o -name "<regexp2>"`
For my case, this is not very handy.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953377/shell-find-files-in-a-list may be of interest.

Comment: Thanks indeed answer my question. For some reason, this answer did not come up in my searches.