# Find files which(Files name) are listed in one file

Tags: linux

I want to find files which(Files name) are listed in one file.

```
cat test.txt
```

```
abc.doc

pqr.txt

xyz.xls

mnp.mp3
```

Output should be

```
/home/folder1/abc.doc

/home/folder1/folder_tmp/pqr.txt

/home/folder2/xyz.xls

/home/mnp.mp3
```

So please give me guidance for the same.

Comment: Of course. Please post your current code.

Comment: His code is the linux command `cat test.txt` he wants to make it return the complete file path not just filenames which he stored in the test.txt? I don't understand how it's possible to predict the filepaths? Nevermind he wants to find them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953377/shell-find-files-in-a-list is a duplicate and contains your solution!

Answer (score 0):

In bash script you can do something like:

```
while read line
do
   #Change ./ by path of search
   echo "$(find ./ -name $line)"
done < path/of/file/test.txt
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for answer.I can do by script but I want single command like by awk etc.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953377/shell-find-files-in-a-list